# Command line argument: 95 -> 1995 and 15 -> 2015

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

If my command line argument input is a number between `32` and `99`, I would like to save this as a variable `int year = Integer.parseInt(args[0])+1900;`, so `year` would go between `1932`and `1999`.

If my command line argument input is a number between `0` and `15`, I would like to save this as the same variable, but `year` would now go between `2000`and `2015`.

I'm already using `try` and `except` to catch `NumberFormatException`, so if the input is not an integer, that shouldn't become a problem.

I couldn't solve this problem with the usage of `if`, `else if` and `else`, because java won't let me use `year` after the `if`-statements, and I need it to calculate another variable. So is there another, better way?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it is a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you parse first and then add 100 if needed

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(args[0])+1900;
if (year < 1916) {
    year += 100;
}
```

I don't see what Java wouldn't allow that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think of that, so because I'm declaring the variable outside the `if`-statement, I'm able to work with it even though it doesn't go into the `if`, right?

Comment: "...able to work with it...?" : Correct! Glad to help - feel free to mark the answer as Correct if this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some code showing what you've tried.

But it sounds like you're having a problem with variable scoping. You most likely need to declare your year variable outside any try or if statement so you can use it in other places in your method.

For example this will not work.

```
try {
    // We're declaring this variable in the try block
    // so it can only be used in the try block
    int year = Integer.parseInt(args[0])+1900;
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
if (/* some boolean statement with year */) { ... }
```

But this will

```
// Here we declare it outside the try and if so we can use it in both
int year = 0;
try {
    year = Integer.parseInt(args[0])+1900;
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
if (/* some boolean statement with year */) { ... }
```